# What is the relativistic basis for the Maxwell-Faraday Law?

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity

I want to preface this by saying that I am well aware of the fact that mathematical proof is not something that exists in physics. Only experiment can "prove" anything physical. However, it is also true that magnetism can, at least within classical electromagnetism, be understood as a consequence of merging Gauss's Law with Einstein's relativity. Therefore, it seems to me that the *properties* of the magnetic field should also logically be consistent with relativity, including its obedience to Maxwell's Equations.

I actually have managed to do the relativity calculations to demonstrate this consistency in one out of the two situations that seem of importance. Let me describe this scenario below.

Imagine a frame $S$ in which there is a magnetic field (constant with time) given by
$$\vec{B}(x)=Cx\hat{y}$$
Now imagine another frame $S'$ that moves with speed $v$ along the $x$ direction. In this frame, there is not only a magnetic field, which here varies in time, but an electric field that also varies through space. The transformations of the electric and magnetic fields can be found here, for reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_electromagnetism_and_special_relativity

I calculated what the $\vec{E'}$ and $\vec{B'}$ fields should look like in frame $S'$, and then showed that they obeyed the Maxwell-Faraday Law. According to the transformation laws:

For the electric field:
$$E_{x'}'=0$$
$$E_{y'}'=0$$
$$E_{z'}'=\gamma vB_{y}=\gamma vCx=\gamma^{2} vC(x'+vt')$$

For the magnetic field:
$$B_{x'}'=0$$
$$B_{y'}'=\gamma B_{y} = \gamma Cx = \gamma^{2} C(x'+vt')$$
$$B_{z'}'=0$$

Putting them together:
$$\frac{\partial{\vec{B'}}}{\partial{t'}}=\gamma^{2} vC\hat{y}'$$
$$\nabla\times\vec{E'}=
\begin{vmatrix}
\hat{x'} & \hat{y'} & \hat{z'} \\
\frac{\partial{}}{\partial{x'}} & \frac{\partial{}}{\partial{y'}} & \frac{\partial{}}{\partial{z'}} \\
0 & 0 & E_{z'}'
\end{vmatrix}=-\frac{\partial{E_{z'}'}}{\partial{x'}}\hat{y}'=-\gamma^{2} vC\hat{y}'$$
$$\frac{\partial{\vec{B'}}}{\partial{t'}}=-\nabla\times\vec{E'}$$

We could have flipped the definitions of $S$ and $S'$, and the primes would be absent. This is the Maxwell-Faraday Law. To me, the calculation above seems to suggest that the law is a consequence of the relativistic field transformations.

However, this is only scenario 1. What about scenario 2, where we imagine that the strength of $\vec{B}$ is uniform in space but varies in time? In this case, we don't have a Lorentz Transformation to perform here; we are already in the frame where the field changes with time. But it was relativity that seemed to suggest an electric field would be produced in the first place. So I don't see an obvious reason why this situation would also be consistent with the Maxwell-Faraday Law. Yet we observe an electric field, so where does it come from?

EDIT: The calculation I did also seems to suggest that the magnitude of the electric field in frame $S'$ from scenario 1 grows with time. This isn't implied by the Maxwell-Faraday Law, is it? Is it implied by the Ampère-Maxwell Law?

Comment: The Lorentz covariance of all of Maxwell’s Equations is transparent when they are written in “manifestly covariant” notation using the EM field 4- tensor $F^{\mu\nu}$. Working with $\mathbf E$ and $\mathbf B$ obscures this.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm going to take a look at this more this weekend when I have time, and hopefully it will become clear to me that this works.